# Flash a notificaton instead of error when I get ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to refresh page and flash a notification to handle an error?
I'm getting this error on my "choose_plan#new" page if the user presses the "checkout#new" button without selecting a plan. I'd prefer to show a nofication instead of only making my button work if they've selected a plan.

The error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Plan without an ID):
```

My code:

```
class ChoosePlanController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @plans = Plan.all

class CheckoutController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan])
```

I'm using rails 7.0.1 and ruby 3.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find_by` which doesn't raise an error and will return `nil` if nothing is found.

```
def new
  if params[:plan].blank?
    redirect_to new_choose_plan_path, notice: "Please, select a plan."
    return
  end

  @plan = Plan.find_by(id: params[:plan])

  unless @plan
    redirect_to new_choose_plan_path, notice: "No plan found."
    return
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: @EmilStåhlMyllyaho then you need to redirect. i've updated the answer.

Comment: I figured it out and deleted my comment the same sec as u commented. Thank u so much :)

Answer (score 1):

[`rescue`](https://stackify.com/rescue-exceptions-ruby/) the error and [`flash`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html) a notice.

```
class CheckoutController < ApplicationController
  def new
    begin
      @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      flash.notice = e
    end

    ...
  end
end
```

You'll probably also want to render something.

Alternatively, you can use `where` and `first` instead of `find`. This will not raise an error, then check if there is a plan.

```
class CheckoutController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @plan = Plan.where(id: params[:plan]).first

    if @plan
      ...
    else
      flash.notice = "Plan not found"
    end
  end
end
```